# paper-icon-button doesn't show the icon

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Hello, I have an application where I want to use paper-icon-button, I'm using a theme Dark [Theme][1], the problem is that I'm not able to make the paper-icon-button to show the icon.

### Imports:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset-svg/iron-iconset-svg.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-iconset/iron-iconset.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/editor-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/communication-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/notification-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/maps-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/social-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icon/iron-icon.html">
<!-- Paper elements -->
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
```

### Element:

```
<dom-module id="my-adminwork">
  <template>
    <style>
      :host {
        display: block;
      },
    </style>
    <iron-localstorage name="my-signasafe-storage" id="localStorage_id" value="{{sessionObject}}"></iron-localstorage>
    <span>Text example</span>
    <paper-icon-button icon="refresh"></paper-icon-button>
  </template>
```

The paper-icon-button supposed to be compound of an iron-icon element that inside have the svg icon, when I checked in the html in the browser I don't see the svg icon code inside the iron-icon element.

Any idea of why is this happening?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have `iron-icons` installed as a dependency? It works fine for me in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/EyWQGO?editors=1000)

Comment: Yes it is installed, in the folder bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html, actually I checked the code for iron-icons.html and all the icons are there

Comment: this is my bower.json:`"private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "app-layout": "polymerelements/app-layout#^0.9.0",
    "app-route": "polymerelements/app-route#^0.9.1",
    "iron-flex-layout": "PolymerElements/iron-flex-layout#^1.3.1",
    "iron-icon": "polymerelements/iron-icon#^1.0.0",
    "iron-iconset-svg": "polymerelements/iron-iconset-svg#^1.0.0",`

Comment: Any console warnings/errors?

Comment: Nop, no error in the console

Comment: Also, you can click in the paper-icon-button and the rippley effect works but no icon on it

Comment: Can you provide a codepen that demonstrates this?

Comment: Sorry what do you need? Is my english I didn't catch what you mean, I put the code that I have in my element, and also the components imported on "element.html"

Comment: Can you create a demo in [Codepen](https://codepen.io) that shows your exact problem? I have a feeling there's some context I'm missing, and your demo could reveal what that is. (If you need a translation of this, please see http://translate.google.com)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't know how to create a polymer snnippet in Codepen and also I don't know if I can reproduce the same, what I can do is sent you the project in a zip file.

Comment: Ok. tony19@gmail.com

Comment: I already sent to you, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you've [defined a custom iconset named **"icons"**](https://github.com/jperera84/signasafe/blob/master/src/my-icons.html#L14), which is the same name as that of Polymer's default iconset. This causes the icon lookup to search your custom iconset in `my-icons.html` for an icon that actually belongs to the default iconset in `iron-icons.html`.

To resolve the issue, change the name of your custom iconset (e.g., to "my-icons").

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help, you don't imagine the problem that you help me with. Thanks again

Comment: @JoseRaulPerera No problem :-)